Time reversal symmetry of Jaynes-Cummings model
Is Jaynes-Cummings (JC) model time-reversal symmetric? The Hamiltonian for JC model is
$H = wa^{\dagger}a+w_0\sigma_z+\Omega(a^{\dagger}\sigma_-+a\sigma_+)$. The annihilation operator must remain invariant under time reversal operation since,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathcal{T}a\mathcal{T}^{-1}\\  
=&&\mathcal{T}(x+ip)\mathcal{T}^{-1}\\
=&&(\mathcal{T}x\mathcal{T}^{-1}+\mathcal{T}i\mathcal{T}^{-1}\mathcal{T}p\mathcal{T}^{-1})\\
=&&(x+(-i)(-p))\\
=&& (x+ip)=a.
\end{eqnarray}
It is also known that the spin operators are odd under time reversal operation $\mathcal{T}\sigma_i\mathcal{T}^{-1}=-\sigma_i \,\,\,(i=x,y,z)$. Therefore, we have $\mathcal{T}\sigma_{\pm}\mathcal{T}^{-1}=-\sigma_{\mp}$. Finally, the time-reversed Hamiltonian can be written as,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{T}H\mathcal{T}^{-1} &=& wa^{\dagger}a+w_0(-\sigma_z)+\Omega(a^{\dagger}(-\sigma_+)+a(-\sigma_-))\\
&=& wa^{\dagger}a-w_0\sigma_z-\Omega(a^{\dagger}\sigma_++a\sigma_-).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, the nature of the interaction is also changing under time reversal operation. So this is neither symmetric not antisymmetric under the time reversal operation. Is it correct? I have not encountered this in the literature.
